# Resta de campos en una página

Tags: php

Estoy creando un página de préstamos pero necesito que cada vez que se haga un préstamo la tabla de material lo valla disminuyendo. Estoy buscando una solución ya que necesito que cada vez que se abra la página de información se pueda ver cuanta cantidad hay de cada material:

```
<thead class="text-warning">
    <tr>
        <th>Nombre del Material</th>
        <th>Cantidad del Material</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
  <?php

  $query="SELECT Material.nom_m, Material.cantida
  
  FROM Material";
  $consulta=$conexion->query($query);
  while ($fila=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    echo'
    <tr>
    <td>'.$fila['nom_m'].'</td>
    <td>'.$fila['cantida'].'</td>
    </tr>
    ';
  }
    
  ?>
```

Este es el código que tengo pero no me realiza la resta.

Comment: No entiendo, porque haces doble igualdad? la variable siempre será 0, de la cual no estarías restando nada...

Comment: Le puse eso por que no me lei nada y me lanzaba un error ahora no lanza en error pero no me lee nada

Comment: creo que no nos estas mostrando todo el codigo necesario, la doble igualdad no hace falta y lo que describes es lo que hace el codigo, pero 0-0  da 0.... De donde salen las variables $cantida && $resta?¿  No se entiende tu objetivo.

Comment: Tienes razón sino que la pagina no me permite mostra el código completo @SeveralTool